# Http Get for attachment

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch a ZIP file (which is normally available to a browser user as a file through a button click).
The HTTP Request goes fine as visible in the chrome - network.
However the HttpClient.get function returns error.
Here is the calling function code

```
const userUri = this.userEnv + 'api/Upload/Download?fileID=' + fileIDResponse;
const userHttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.authToken,
    responseType: 'blob'
  })
};
this.http.get(userUri,
  userHttpOptions).subscribe(fileResponse => console.log(fileIDResponse),
    fileError => console.log(fileError)
  );
```

The request header in Dev  Tools -> Network, gives `Status Code: 200 OK`.

> The fileError which is echoed to console says
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
>    at JSON.parse ()
>    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:2291:51)

How do I modify my code to give ResponseType?

Best Regards,
Vinayak

Comment: try with JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: @SantoshSingh —What would be the point of expressing a zip file as JSON?

Comment: What does the HTTP response look like? Angular [says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) *If the Content-Type is application/json or the response looks like JSON, deserialize it using a JSON parser* but you said you were returning a ZIP file, so it shouldn't have that content-type nor should it look like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const userHttpOptions = {
>   headers: new HttpHeaders({
>     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.authToken,
>     responseType: 'blob'
>   })
> };
> ```

`responseType` is an option in its own right. It is not an HTTP request header. You should put it as an option, not a header.

```
const userHttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.authToken
  }),
  responseType: 'blob'
};
```

Presumably, this is why Angular is misinterpreting the response data as JSON.

Comment: For me <responseType: 'Blob' > worked. Blob with a capital "B". Not able to modify the answer.